# Check for Date in String - jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, date, search, filter

Okay, this might be a crazy question and not simple to do, but here's what I'm attempting to do:

I have a textarea on my todo list application I created where users can quickly add a task without going through the add task form and adding all the details to it (for when they're too busy to). I want to be able to search the text they entered to see if there's a date there. If it makes it simpler, I can search for only dates in a YYYY-MM-DD or similar format.

For example, if their text says:

> "I need to plan my graduation party by 2014-05-07"

I want to be able to move the "2014-05-07" part to its own field in the database, and move the entire string to a different field. Any ideas on how I could do this? I'm using PHP, jQuery, and MySQL, so if there's a way to do it in another language, I'm open to it.

Comment: Regex, in either php or js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use preg_match() to extract the date string. then store the matches separately.

```
<?php
$str = 'I need to plan my graduation party by 2014-05-07';
if(preg_match('@/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/@', $str, $matches))
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` is what you are looking for, specifically:

```
if(preg_match('/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/',$date)){
   //dothis
}else{
   //dothat
}
```

if you REALLY ONLY want properly formatted date, then

`/\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d [0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d/`